# How to convert a date to YYYYDDD?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I can't figure out how to turn Sys.Date() into a number in the format YYYYDDD. Where DDD is the day of the year, i.e. Jan 1 would be 2016001 Dec 31 would be 2016365

```
Date <- Sys.Date()  ## The Variable Date is created as 2016-01-01
SomeFunction(Date)  ## Returns 2016001
```

Comment: @katya-handler

Basically every other format(Date, ) function, didn't realize %j existed. 

If others exist I would love to know, was referencing this site: 

[link](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

Comment: The `format` section in the documentation of [`as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) links to the relevant documentation of [`strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) where all date-time conversion specifications are listed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the `format` function as follows:

```
format(Date, '%Y%j')
```

which gives:

```
[1] "2016161" "2016162" "2016163"
```

If you want to format it in other ways, see `?strptime` for all the possible options.

Alternatively, you could use the `year` and `yday` functions from the `data.table` or `lubridate` packages and paste them together with `paste0`:

```
library(data.table) # or: library(lubridate)
paste0(year(Date), yday(Date))
```

which will give you the same result.

---

The values that are returned by both options are of class character. Wrap the above solutions in `as.numeric()` to get real numbers.

---

Used data:

```
> Date <- Sys.Date() + 1:3
> Date
[1] "2016-06-09" "2016-06-10" "2016-06-11"
> class(Date)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks a ton.

Comment: maybe a deeper question to help me learn: How did you know that %j existed? I didn't come across this anywhere else.

Comment: @LanceScadden See `?strptime`

Comment: Would this smells like a dupe ? :-)

Comment: @akrun probably it is; if you have a good one, go ahead and close it

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option with `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- Sys.Date()
#[1] "2016-06-08"
paste0(year(x),yday(x))
#[1] "2016160"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for creating a new column with the specified date format:

```
Date <- Sys.Date    
df$Month_Yr <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y%d")
```

But, especially when working with larger data sets, it is easier to do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,NewDate := format(as.Date(Date), "%Y%d"
```

Hope this helps. May have to tinker if you only want one value and are not working with a data set.

Comment: @mtoto has a good, simple answer if just looking for that specific value.